# Execute JS function just before page close | redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

## Question:

I am using ASP.NET web forms, c#.

I need to execute a JS function just before the page closes - any which way it closes - being a redirect or any other method.

**Extra Info:**

As some extra info; the function will be an HTTP POST to a different page, I need some server side code to execute.

With this info in mind - a solution allowing me to execute server-side code when a page closes will work for me as well.

Comment: No can do, not possible.  That feature was far too abused by people in the past.  There *is* a onpageunload event, but there is nothing to ensure that your ajax won't time out first -- and in fact it's likely.  Also no way to handle a "page close" network connection is lost, power goes away, etc.

Comment: Since this is a client side feature, you wouldn't need a solution that relates to ASP.NET, but only JavaScript

Comment: I thought it might be impossible. Going to have think of some other solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the JavaScript function `window.onbeforeunload`.

Essentially, browsers fire this event when they detect that the page is closing, and allow you to customize a message by returning a string from this function.

You cannot however, control if the user wants to force close the page early, or unexpectedly.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    // do some ajax post here
    // 

    // Display a message (or generic message in some browsers) and allow the user to cancel leaving the page.
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Note that this solution tries to warn the user and allows the unload to be cancelled. This might not be ideal for you, but should work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload